# Can I add the new link as well as Set the audience in CurrentNavSiteMapProvider in SharePoint Publishing Site Using Code?

Tags: navigation

How can i add the new link as well as set the audience in currentNavSiteMapProvider in SharePoint Publishing using SharePoint Object Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this method

```
public void SetNavigation()
    {
        using (SPSite Site = new SPSite("http://YourWeb"))
        using (SPWeb Web = Site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPNavigationNode navNode = Web.Navigation.GlobalNodes[0];

            if (navNode.Properties.Contains("Audience"))
            {
                navNode.Properties["Audience"] = ";;;;YourSiteMembers,YourSiteOwners";
            }
            else
            {
                navNode.Properties.Add("Audience", ";;;;YourSiteMembers,YourSiteOwners");
            }
            navNode.Update();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I just wanted to confirm that I wanted to add the links in **Current navigation** not in  GlobalNodes. Is this code work for SharePoint Current navigation.

Comment: Global and current work the same as far as I know. I have used this for current as well.

Comment: I test the above code but I am unable to get the values audience properties. FYI I am getting the properties like "vti_nonnavpage" ect.

Comment: Sorry forgot the update line. Added navNode.Update()

Comment: Did this solve your issue? if so would you mind marking it as answered?